# mathematica table list values

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I generate a table where the elements in the table come from a named list? Why isn't the list being evaluated?

```
f[x_] := 3 x - 2;
lx_values = {1, 1.5, 1.9, 1.99, 1.999};
Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, lx_values}]
```

Table::iterb: Iterator {x,lx_values} does not have appropriate bounds. >>
Table[{x,f(x)},{x,lx_values}]

Comment: You cannot use underscores in variable names. Fix that and it will work fine.

Comment: Check [Blank](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html?q=Blank) to see why underscores can't be used in variable names.

Comment: Thank you!
It's too bad the error message isn't more helpful